# Transfer Data from UserForm to Worksheet Cells using vba

Tags: vba, userform

Please see below the code I am using so far. I do not get an error but the userform data is not being transferred into the worksheet cell. Would greatly appreciate any help, thanks!

```
Private Sub OKButton_Click()

Dim emptyRow As Long
Sheet7.Activate

emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 16

Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = FileNameTextBox.Text
Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = PricingSheetListBox.Text
```

Comment: instead of activating the sheet, assign each range object to the parent `Sheet7.Range("A:A")` and `Sheet7.Cells(emptyRow,...)`  And make sure that the code name `Sheet7` actually refers to the correct sheet, which could be named differently.

Comment: Thank you for the response Scott. What do you mean by the correct code name for the sheet though? When I open the VBA project, it says Sheet7 (Master), with Master ebing the name of the sheet in the workbook

Comment: Then `Sheet7` is the code name and `Master` is the sheet name.  Many people will confuse the code name with the sheet name, then wonder why the code is changing the wrong sheet.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, Scott. I tried what you suggested (please see code below) but it is still not working, Could you tell me whats wrong?

Comment: Private Sub OKButton_Click()

Dim emptyRow As Long
Sheet7.Activate

emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 16

Sheet7.Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = FileNameTextBox.Text
Sheet7.Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = PricingSheetListBox.Text